# sscanf until it reaches a comma

Tags: c, string, scanf

I'm trying to scanf words and numbers from a string looks like: "**hello, world, I, 287876, 6.0**"   <-- this string is stored in a `char` array (string)
What I need to do is to split things up and assign them to different variables so it would be like

```
     char a = "hello"
     char b = "world"
     char c = "I"
     unsigned long d = 287876
     float e = 6.0
```

I know that regular scanf stops reading from stdin when it reaches a white space. So I've been thinking that there might be a way to make sscanf stop reading when it reaches a **","** (comma)

I've been exploring the library to find a format for sscanf to read only alphabet and numbers. I couldn't find such a thing, maybe I should look once more.

Any help?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: e.g)`"%[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %lu, %f"`

Comment: the order of your variables in the string is it fixe? I mean It's always: `string, string, char, int, float` ?

Comment: yeah, I think this will work: "%[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %lu, %f"

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : How I can do it the same way for scanning until it match a particular substring?

Comment: @FaisalAl-shawi : How I can do it the same way for scanning until it match a particular substring?

Comment: @user2284570 `scanf` can not be specified that read until to match a particular part string. you can use `strstr` for find to particular part string. You should post as questions rather than a comment.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : but`ststr()`will return a pointer to the substring isn’t it? I want to match until a substring : let’s say I have`"x -fx some stuff compressed-encoding=some mime type"`and I want the string part before`" compressed-encoding="`.

Comment: @user2284570 copy until to position of pointer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : is there really no`%*^`sscanf like solution?

Comment: @user2284570 you can't such because `[...]` is specified character set, not string(character sequence).

Comment: @user2284570 It is not possible to such specified in `scanf`.

Comment: @user2284570 Such interaction will be nuisance for this article. again, You should be posted as your question.

Answer (score 22):

If the order of your variables in the string is fixe, I mean It's always:

```
string, string, string, int, float
```

the use the following format specifier in `sscanf()`:

```
int len = strlen(str);
char a[len];
char b[len];
char c[len];
unsigned long d;
float e;

sscanf(" %[^,] , %[^,] , %[^,] , %lu , %lf", a, b, c, &d, &e);
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing. Thanks

Comment: @MOHAMED : How I can do it for scanning until it match a particular substring?

Comment: For safety, the arrays should be defined with a length of `len + 1`, since `e` is a float, the last format should be `%f` and some of the spaces in the format string are redundant: `" %[^,], %[^,], %[^,],%lu,%f"`

Answer (score 1):

This example using `strtok` should be helpful:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="hello, world, I, 287876, 6.0" ;
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str,",");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the format of the text file is constant you can use the following solution.

```
std::ifstream ifs("datacar.txt");
    if(ifs)
    {
       std::string line;
       while(std::getline(ifs,line))
       {
            /* optional to check number of items in a line*/
            std::vector<std::string> row;
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            std::copy(
                std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
                std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                std::back_inserter(row)
            );

            /*To avoid parsing the first line and avoid any error in text file */
            if(row.size()<=2)
                continue;


            std::string format = "%s %s %s %f %[^,] %d";
            char year[line.size()],make[line.size()],three[line.size()],full[line.size()];
            float numberf;
            int numberi;  

            std::sscanf(line.c_str(),format.c_str(),&year,&make,&three,&numberf,&full,&numberi);

        /* create your object and parse the next line*/


        }

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

See the documentation for `strtok` and/or `strtok_r`

Comment: I'm not sure if it is or it isn't -- hence the "AND/OR" in my response. **IF** the `strtok_r` flavor is supported, it is thread safe and recursion safe, not a global state function as is `strtok` -- either way... one variant of `strtok` or another is a solution to the problem.

Comment: For the record... `strtok_r` is `POSIX.1-2001`